# Elixir Finch not returning all of the tags, like the meta tags

Tags: elixir

Elixir Finch is not returning all the headers I see when I visit a page.

Some of the tags are missing, in particular the meta tags.

I've tried using  `:httpc.request(:get, {url, []}, [], [])}` as well to no avail.

Why am I not getting the meta tags?

Comment: Finch is just an HTTP client. Are you expecting it to parse the HTML and convert the meta tags to headers for you? It won't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a simple plug:

```elixir
defmodule MyPlug do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options) do
    # initialize options
    options
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_header("meta", "foo")
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
    |> send_resp(200, "Hello world")
  end

  def get do
    Finch.build(:get, "http://localhost:4001") |> Finch.request(MyFinch)
  end
end
```

Calling it:

```elixir
iex(1)> MyPlug.get
{:ok,
 %Finch.Response{
   status: 200,
   body: "Hello world",
   headers: [
     {"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"},
     {"content-length", "11"},
     {"content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8"},
     {"date", "Sun, 25 Sep 2022 01:20:53 GMT"},
     {"meta", "foo"},
     {"server", "Cowboy"}
   ]
 }}
```

The `meta` header is returned.